# Validate required ui-select field

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ui-select

I'm new with angular, and I need a way to validate a ui-select field, I have tried with

> ng-required="true"

and with

> requiered

But as none of those work now I want to use bootstrap has-error class to show that the field is required, this is my code.

```
<div class="form-group">
<div ng-class="{'has-error': !project.parentOrganization || project.parentOrganization == ''}">
<ui-select ng-model="project.parentOrganization" theme="bootstrap" reset-search-input="true" tabindex="4" ng-required="true" id="{{'itopOrganizationId' + $index}}" required>
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Seleccione una organización padre">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="value.id as value in parentOrganizations | filter: {name: $select.search} | orderBy:'name'">
    <div ng-bind-html="value.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

And this is part of my controller

```
    $scope.saveProject = function () {

  if(!$scope.project.parentOrganization || $scope.project.parentOrganization == ""){
    return
 }
```

Now the problem is that when the modal shows up it's already marked with red, I need to do it after the submit button click.

What should I do? Do you have a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a form like this

```
<form ng-form="example" novalidate>
<div class="form-group">
<div ng-class="{'has-error': example.project.parentOrganization.$invalid && !example.project.parentOrganization.$pristine}">
<ui-select name="project.parentOrganization" ng-model="project.parentOrganization" theme="bootstrap" reset-search-input="true" tabindex="4" ng-required="true" id="{{'itopOrganizationId' + $index}}" required>
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Seleccione una organización padre">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="value.id as value in parentOrganizations | filter: {name: $select.search} | orderBy:'name'">
    <div ng-bind-html="value.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
</form>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.example={}
$scope.saveProject = function () {

  if(!$scope.project.parentOrganization || $scope.project.parentOrganization == ""){
      $scope.example.project.parentOrganization.$pristine=false; 
      return
    }
```